# Can I run startx via SSH?

Tags: ssh, x11

I have a computer with a monitor and network connection, but no keyboard.

When I turn on the computer, the screen shows virtual terminal number 1 (VT1).

Is there a way to run startx on VT1 through SSH?

Comment: What are you trying to do? You want to have some sort of remote desktop through SSH?

Comment: `ssh -Y user@host.example.com startx` should open a local X session connected to an X server on the remote host.

Comment: @phk. Well, yes. Once I have X started, it's easy. Just set DISPLAY. The question is how to get there :)

Comment: @DopeGhoti No. The goal is to have everything remote. The program and server.

Comment: for that, use `sudo init 5`.

Comment: @DopeGhoti yes, with xdm and auto login

Comment: @x11: you can switch the virtual terminal from the command line using `chvt`. (e.g. `chvt 7` is equivalent to Ctrl+Alt+F7). If the issue is that it's on the wrong screen, that might help.

Comment: @x11 -- X2go is a pretty cool tool that allows you to run X from a remote system using SSH. Might work for what you are talking about here....

Comment: FWIW I think this question is perfectly clear. [Here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/554603/118662) is a solution involving Systemd.