# How to manually run/init/start a Xorg server on a different VT/TTY?

Tags: xorg, tty, xinit, chvt

I want to start an Xorg server (which should only feature a minimal `xterm` terminal emulator from a newly created "pristine" `tty`). I have thought this to be as simple as issuing a `xinit` or maybe a `startx` however both have failed me. Therefore the question:

**How to manually run/init/start a Xorg server on a different VT/TTY?**

here the

### Longer background story to the question at hand:

This is the backgroud and what I have tried already:

Looking at `man openvt` I was able to run a shell on a newly created `tty` (or `vt`, cannot tell precisly the different *vt*<>*tty*) like this:

```
 $> sudo openvt -s /bin/bash
```

the `-s` of causes the direct switch to that new tty/vt
on that new tty I wanted to manually start a `Xorg` server which according to `man xinit` should start with a minimal `xterm` application. On the new shell on the switched to tty I (created via `openvt`) I hence issues this command:

```
 $> su -c 'xinit xterm -display :4 -- :4' - mahr &>/tmp/output
```

and I receive this output

```
$> cat /tmp/output
X.Org X Server 1.19.6
Release Date: 2017-12-20
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux 4.4.0-148-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
Current Operating System: Linux scitech 4.15.0-70-generic #79-Ubuntu SMP Tue Nov 12 10:36:11 UTC 2019 x86_64
Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-4.15.0-70-generic root=/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root ro
Build Date: 03 June 2019  08:10:35AM
xorg-server 2:1.19.6-1ubuntu4.3 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
Current version of pixman: 0.34.0
    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(==) Log file: "/home/mahr/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.4.log", Time: Thu Nov 28 10:57:53 2019
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
(EE) 
Fatal server error:
(EE) parse_vt_settings: Cannot open /dev/tty0 (Permission denied)
(EE) 
(EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
(EE) Please also check the log file at "/home/mahr/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.4.log" for additional information.
(EE) 
(EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.

Session terminated, terminating shell...xinit: giving up
xinit: unable to connect to X server: Connection refused
xinit: unexpected signal 2
 ...terminated.
```

Comment: If memory serves, adding your user to the `tty` group should help with your issue.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm getting what you're after (won't a new Xserver start in a new/free vt by default? there's no relationship between the vt and the display number), but you should use the `vtN` Xorg arg (where `N` is the tty number) if you want it to run in a particular tty. Try something like `openvt -s -- sh -c 'tty=$(tty); startx xterm -- :2 vt${tty#*tty}'`.

Comment: notice that `xinit` won't set up any auth by default, so any program running in the Xorg server is _completely open_ to any user. Don't use it.

Comment: thank you @mosvy I will attempt to move along with the things you suggested :)  Any idea why there is a `tty` group and what a membership entails? is there a quick thing to know about it, some history?

Comment: note it may not be possible to start a server on a "different" VT than the currently active one (there's probably a way if you don't mind switching the VT though). https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/539071/why-is-it-not-possible-to-start-x-in-the-background

Comment: @sourcejedi But would it not be possible to use the `openvt` with the `-s` flag to switch to the tty and subsequently run the `xinit`/`startx`, maybe even supplied via the `command` command line argument?

Comment: @fraleone ah, sorry. I didn't check what the `-s` flag of `openvt` does.

Comment: when you say `startx` and `xinit` have failed you, do you mean they *fail* with an undisclosed (!) error message , or do you mean they don't do what you want, e.g. do not open in a new VT, or open more than a single xterm?

Comment: If you run _any command_ via `su other_user` it won't be able to open the terminal via a path, this is not specific to Xorg or virtual terminals. Eg. these will fail: `su other_user -c 'echo >/dev/stdout'`, `su other_user -c 'echo > $(tty)'`, `su other_user -c 'echo >/dev/tty'`, etc.

Answer (score 5):

**Do not use `xinit`, because it is vulnerable**.  Use `startx`.  `xinit` appears to be written to accept X connections from any user ID, without warning or documentation.  `startx` appears to fix this.  I do not know why this situation is tolerated, or how it happened in the first place.

The way `X` works has changed "recently".  `X` used to rely on being set-uid root, and switch to a new VT.  Note, even then, `X` might only have worked if you started it from a text VT.  E.g. a non-root user might not be able to start `X` from inside another `X` session.  In other words, I'm not sure whether this would do what you want anyway.

X has now been changed so that it can use the *current* VT instead.  Some tools such as `startx` have changed their behaviour, to use the new design.

The design is you do not need to start any program as root (in order to improve security).  This works by using `logind` instead, a smaller background service (which is started with root privileges).

If you went back to running `X` as root, you would not need permission from `logind`.  I think `X` will probably remain compatible with this.

You appear to have been trying to run `X` without forcing it to run as full `root`.  In that case you need permission from `logind`.  `logind` gives you permission to do stuff *on the VT you logged in on*.  I worked out a trick to [spoof a login](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/346383/run-second-x-server-from-within-x-as-a-systemd-service/473041#473041).

```
user=mahr
sudo systemd-run \
    --property PAMName=login \
    --property User="$user" \
    --property StandardInput=tty \
    --property TTYPath=/dev/tty8 \
    sh -c 'chvt 8 && exec startx /usr/bin/xterm'
```

---

It feels like it should be possible to allocate the tty dynamically as well (using `openvt -s`, and a script using the `tty` command).  However, I have just frozen my screen a couple of times trying to do that :-).

(`logind` *intended* to reduce how much damage non-root programs like this X server can do to the system.  AIUI the implementation of this is quite limited.  It does not provide a recovery key.  `logind` even gets killed horribly if you use the kernel System Attention Key.)

Even after using the kernel command SysRQ + R, I could not recover the screen.  I think something broke, probably `logind` or `gdm` :-).

Comment: I have tried your command, and it started a xinit process on the specified `tty8` which then sadly shows the same error message as I have shown in my question above. Thanks stilll

Comment: @fraleone thanks for your specific feedback! Please can you edit your question, to show the name and version of the operating system(s) that produces this result.

Comment: @fraleone If it's a rolling distro, include the version of the package that provides `xinit`.

Comment: @fraleone ok! someone says [startx might work](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=856351). If you just ran `xinit` in a logged-in text VT, does it fail with the same error? Does my command work if you replace `xinit xterm -- :8` with `sh -c 'chvt 8 && exec startx /usr/bin/xterm'` ?

Answer (score 2):

by my test, your commands will work well if you put this 2 lines in **/etc/X11/Xwrapper.config** :

```
allowed_users=anybody
needs_root_rights=yes
```

it seems that X server starting is by default allowed only to user that is the owner of target virtual terminal and physically (keyboard) connected to it. (your case: root is vt-owner, and x tried to run as 'mahr').

This two lines overrides that request, and makes even possible starting all from one command, one terminal (useful for init scripts or remote x starting with ssh).

```
sudo openvt -c15 -- su user -c 'xinit /usr/bin/xterm -display :15 -- :15 vt15'
```

Comment: this one did work

Answer (score 0):

Here is my version of @sourcejedi's [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/554603/118662) (sorry, it wouldn't go in a comment):

```
#!/bin/sh                     
# login-spoof

# Pretend that we're running a command after having logged into a
# given virtual terminal as us. Example:

# $ ./login-spoof 8 startx /usr/bin/xterm -- :1
# Running as unit: run-r3cc564bee3134c789c09c21faee9e710.service
# (opens xterm on /dev/tty8)

TTYNUM=$1; shift
sudo systemd-run \
    --property PAMName=login \
    --property User="$USER" \
    --property StandardInput=tty \
    --property TTYPath=/dev/tty$TTYNUM \
    sh -c 'export PATH="'$PATH'"; chvt '$TTYNUM' && exec "$@"' x "$@"
```

Comment: Instead of jumping around quoting like that, you could use `env`: `env "PATH=$PATH" "TTYNUM=$TTYNUM" sh -c 'chvt $TTYNUM && exec "$@"' x "$@"`.